# Recreate test db from development db in rails/postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.1

strong textActually I'm using pgAdmin to manage PostgreSQL development database in a rails application.

I've defined the following constraints on USERS table:

```
 CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
 CONSTRAINT users_name_key UNIQUE (name ),
 CONSTRAINT users_age_check CHECK (age > 16),
```

But when I do `rake:db:test:clone` the test database copy the development structure except the  above constraints.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be related to pgAdmin at all.

Comment: Yeah!!!, I mention pgadmin to inform you about the environment I'm working on.But anyway I've removed pgadmin mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really necessary to clone your DB with Ruby? Isn't it easier to create your clone from within Postgres using create Db with template?

Comment: Thanks vergage, that's a good point.I've tried recreate test db from development db template, but the problem when I run 'rake test' the command purge the test database & recreate a new one without the constraints